GoRouter + Keycloak redirect issue. Any ideas?
I am currently working on a web app that uses Flutter with go_router for navigation. I am also using Keycloak to manage the authentication. I am having some trouble on the redirect portion of my app and was curious if anyone had some ideas what is going on here...
I am able to see Keycloak is redirecting as expected, in the address bar of my browser I get the following: http://localhost:5555/landing?session_state=...&code=...
But I am unable to see anything in the GoRouterState except that I am handling a redirect and my router does not pick up the fact I am trying to hit /landing.
Here is my routing code:
final routeProvider = Provider<GoRouter>((ref) =>
    GoRouter(
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
              path: "/",
              pageBuilder: (context, state) => CustomTransitionPage<void>(
                key: state.pageKey,
                child: LandingView(pathParams: {
                  "path": state.fullPath ?? "Unknown",
                  "pathParams": "${state.pathParameters}",
                  "extras": "${state.extra}",
                },),
                transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) =>
                    FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: child)
              ),

              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                    path: LandingView.routeName,
                    pageBuilder: (context, state) => CustomTransitionPage<void>(
                        key: state.pageKey,
                        child: LandingView(pathParams: {
                          "path": state.fullPath ?? "Unknown",
                          "pathParams": "${state.pathParameters}",
                          "extras": "${state.extra}",
                        },),
                        transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) =>
                            FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: child)
                    ),
                ),
              ]
          )
        ],
        redirect: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          log("Redirecting.. path ${state.uri.queryParameters}");
          final userInfo = ref.watch(userDataProvider);

          if(userInfo.value?.authorization != null) {
            return null;
          } else {
            return "/";
          }

        }
    )
);

called in my main.dart file with:
return MaterialApp.router(
      
      routerConfig: myRouter,

      //rest of code omitted
);

I am expecting to be able to access the session_code and code variables from the path after getting redirected from Keycloak.
I have also attempted running in debug and release mode to make sure it was not related to one of those settings.
Network Snapshot
